# How to interpret the components exposed by Facet API in Features?

Tags: features, search

I'm developing a website in Drupal 7 when there is a content type representing research papers that has, among other things, fields representing the author (different from the Drupal user), keywords, topics and geographic zones (the last two are taxonomies, others are text).

To search among them, I'm testing with the Search API (with database index) and the Facet API. My goal is to search using the title and the fields mentioned above. In the Facets tab, I'm only enabling blocks for Topics and Geographic Zones.

I'm using too the Features module to export all the site configuration in source code. When I go to the Create Feature page, I can understand the components under the "Server" and "Index" category, as they have the same name I set to them (there is only one server and one index).

However, when I check the "Facet API" category, I find the following components:

- search_api@paper_index::field_geo_zone
- search_api@paper_index::field_topics
- search_api@paper_index:block:field_keywords
- search_api@paper_index:block:field_author
- search_api@paper_index:block:field_geo_zone
- search_api@paper_index:block:field_topics
- search_api@paper_index:block:search_api_language
- search_api@paper_index:block:title

I can't fully understand the meaning of each component. Why two of them doesn't have the 'block' part? If I only want to have facet blocks for topics and zones, it is necessary to export all of these components or only some of them?